# RowFragment from Leanback library without BrowseFragment

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

in the leanback library, we can create RowFragment inside the BrowseFragment which will include the animation and expanding the views.
This is the normal RowFragment inside BrowseFragment:

- before hide headers
  [image]

-after hide headers
[image]

the project above is from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase)

I tried to implement the Rows Fragment alone in my app without the BrowseFragment. I tried to copy the files, but without BrowseFragment, it looks like this now:
[image]

there's also no margin between items. and when zoomed, the first item got cropped. I tried to add padding in the fragment but it got even more cropped

[image]

here's the main code that I copied from the project:

```
public class PageRowFragment extends RowsSupportFragment {
    private final ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter;

    public PageRowFragment() {
        mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ShadowRowPresenterSelector());

        setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
        setOnItemViewClickedListener(new OnItemViewClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(
                    Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder,
                    Object item,
                    RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder,
                    Row row) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Implement click handler", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        createRows();
//        getMainFragmentAdapter().getFragmentHost().notifyDataReady(getMainFragmentAdapter());
    }

    private void createRows() {
        String json = Util.inputStreamToString(getResources().openRawResource(
                R.raw.page_row_example));
        CardRow[] rows = new Gson().fromJson(json, CardRow[].class);
        for (CardRow row : rows) {
            if (row.getType() == CardRow.TYPE_DEFAULT) {
                mRowsAdapter.add(createCardRow(row));
            }
        }
    }

    private Row createCardRow(CardRow cardRow) {
        PresenterSelector presenterSelector = new CardPresenterSelector(getActivity());
        ArrayObjectAdapter adapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(presenterSelector);
        for (Card card : cardRow.getCards()) {
            adapter.add(card);
        }

        HeaderItem headerItem = new HeaderItem(cardRow.getTitle());
        return new CardListRow(headerItem, adapter, cardRow);
    }
}
```

what should I add so the layout will be the same like the second image?
Thank you!

Comment: You mean `setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED);` in BrowseSupportFragment ?

Comment: First,
Stop copying, Understand why and how it is being used, You just need 

setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED)

this statement. An example is already given there in the same project.